# Count total number of nested one to many relationships

Tags: performance, db2, subquery

Tables: `Users`, `Costs`, `Payments`

Users can have many costs. Costs can have many payments

I want to get information about the user AND count of all payments that they made

This query returns result but takes very long time to run

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(p.id)
    FROM payments AS p
    WHERE p.cost_id IN (SELECT cost_id FROM costs WHERE user_id = u.id)
  ) AS payments_made
FROM users as u;
```

I tried outer joins but then it return duplicate if user has more than one cost

Inner join dropped all users that didn't have a cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this covers your desired result.

> ```
> create table users (user_id int primary key, name varchar(20));
> insert into users values(1, 'john'), (2, 'anne'), (3, 'peter');
>
> create table costs(cost_id int primary key, user_id int);
> insert into costs values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2);
>
> create table payments(payment_id int primary key, cost_id int);
> insert into payments values
> (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 13 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select   c.user_id, count(*) num_payments
> from     payments p
> join     costs c
> on       p.cost_id = c.cost_id
> group by c.user_id
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | num_payments
> ------: | -----------:
>       1 |            5
>       2 |            2
> ```

> ```
> select    u.user_id, u.name, coalesce(p.num_payments, 0) num_payments
> from      users u
> left join (select   c.user_id, count(*) num_payments
>            from     payments p
>            join     costs c
>            on       p.cost_id = c.cost_id
>            group by c.user_id) p
> on         u.user_id = p.user_id           
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | name  | num_payments
> ------: | :---- | -----------:
>       1 | john  |            5
>       2 | anne  |            2
>       3 | peter |            0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddf0237550fdf9a3bfca63b3d7f444d0)*

Or better a left join solution:

> ```
> select    u.user_id, u.name, count(p.payment_id) num_payments
> from      users u
> left join costs c
> on        u.user_id = c.user_id
> left join payments p
> on        p.cost_id = c.cost_id
> group by  u.user_id, u.name
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | name  | num_payments
> ------: | :---- | -----------:
>       1 | john  |            5
>       2 | anne  |            2
>       3 | peter |            0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3d19bf7c4b86b7d174c57992c2c6b9ce)*

Comment: Thank you very much! The first one worked perfectly! Left join solution works as well but it's not as easy to add more columns from user. Well done :)

Comment: I'm glad to help